# Ошибка при вводе значений массива

Tags: c#, rider

Ввожу массив таким способом:

```
using System;

namespace TestConsole
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
        //string[] a = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        //string[] a = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');


            int[] b = new int[5];
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                b[j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (var VARIABLE in b)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

При вводе первого же числа выскакивает ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выведите строку перед тем, как скармливать её функции `Convert.ToInt32`, чтобы посмотреть, в чём проблема. Может, у вас лишние пробелы в начале или в конце? Или десятичный разделитель не соответствует текущему языку. Или слишком много цифр, не влазит в `Int32`. Без этого мы вряд ли сможем понять, в чём проблема.

Comment: @VladD поправил вопрос

Comment: точно лишних пробелов нет?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper точно. В похожей программе, кстати вывод работает если не с клавиатуры вводить, а вставлять строки...(

Comment: попробуйте такой код `for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                var str = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Str  = {0}", str);
                Console.WriteLine(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str));
                b[j] = Convert.ToInt32(str);
            }`и покажите скриншот, практически уверен что попадается пустая строка.

Comment: @Ev_Hyper `12
Str = 12
False
Str = 
True
`

Comment: Он почему-то не ожидает ввода второй раз. Т.е. первый раз все нормально, но потом как будто не заходит в метод readline

Comment: наоборот, как уже говорил - считывает пробельный символ как новую строку.

Comment: ...похоже на следующий баг - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-400

Comment: @Ev_Hyper ну это треш какой-то. Я не совсем понял, это баг ide? Надо в тех поддержку писать ?

Comment: да, выглядит как баг, лучше напишите - лишним не будет.